# FirstOrDefault with Multiple Conditions

Tags: linq-to-sql

In Link to Sql, this works fine:

```
User user = this.dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_ID == loginID);
```

However, I would like to search using conditions like:

```
User user = this.dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(
     p => p.User_ID == 250 && p => p.UserName == "Jack");
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
var user = this.dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(
     p => p.User_ID == 250 && p.UserName == "Jack");
```

The `p =>` at the beginning counts for the whole expression. The syntax used here is a shorthand for

```
(p) =>
      {
         return p.User_ID == 250 && p.UserName == "Jack";
      }
```

Comment: is there any benefit adding condition in FirstOrDefault instead of in Where?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Mainly readability. If you only want to select one, using `users.Where(x => x.Id == 250).FirstOrDefault();` is the same as saying `users.FirsrOrDefault(x => x.Id == 250);`

There's also Single/SingleOrDefault() which are the equivalent of First/FirstOrDefault but will throw a `System.InvalidOperationException` if more than one result is matched in the set. This is useful when you want an exception raised if you are expecting only a single matching record.